# Prevent nested lists in text-editor (froala)

Tags: nested, html-lists, froala

I need to prevent/disable nested lists in text editor implemented in Angular. So far i wrote a hack that undos a nested list when created by the user. But if the user creates a normal list and presses the tab-key the list is shown as nested for a few milliseconds until my hack sets in back to a normal list. I need something like event.preventDefault() or stopPropagation() on tab-event keydown but unfortunately that event is not tracked for some reason. Also the froala settings with `tabSpaces: false`is not showing any difference when it comes to nested list...in summary i want is: if the user creates a list and presses the tab-key that nothing happens, not even for a millisecond. Has anyone an idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

Froala’s support told us, there’s no built-in way to suppress nested list creation. They result from TAB key getting hit with the caret on a list item. However we found a way to get around this using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Basically we move the now nested list item to his former sibling and remove the newly created list. Finally we take care of the caret position.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(mutationObserverCallback);

observer.observe(editorNode, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });

var mutationObserverCallback = function (mutationList) {

    var setCaret = function (ele) {
        if (ele.nextSibling) {
            ele = ele.nextSibling;
        }

        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(ele, 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    };

    var handleAddedListNode = function (listNode) {

        if (! listNode.parentNode) {
            return;
        }

        var parentListItem = listNode.parentNode.closest('li');

        if (!parentListItem) {
            return;
        }

        var idx = listNode.children.length - 1;

        while (idx >= 0) {
            var childNode = listNode.children[idx];

            if (parentListItem.nextSibling) {
                parentListItem.parentNode.insertBefore(childNode, parentListItem.nextSibling);
            } else {
                parentListItem.parentNode.appendChild(childNode);
            }

            --idx;
        }

        setCaret(parentListItem);

        listNode.parentNode.removeChild(listNode);
    };

    mutationList.forEach(function (mutation) {

        var addedNodes = mutation.addedNodes;

        if (!addedNodes.length) {
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < addedNodes.length; i++) {

            var currentNode = addedNodes[i];

            switch (currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'ol':
                case 'ul':
                    handleAddedListNode(currentNode);
                    break;

                // more optimizations
            }

        }

    })
};
```